# Determine if the sequence is convergent or divergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

(a). The first sequence is shown as:

$$a_n = n\sin\left(\frac 1 n \right)$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty} n\sin\left(\frac 1 n\right)
                            = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sin\left(\frac 1 n \right)}{\frac 1 n} = \lim_{n\to0} \frac{\sin(n)} n = 1$$ Thus converges.
Is this correct?

(b). The second sequence is:

$$a_n = \frac{(-1)^n n}{n+1}$$

How to do the limit of this sequence?

Comment: Comment on (a): It's almost correct: Simply avoid to denote $n$ a variable which tends to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: observe subsequences: $${ a }_{ 2n }=\frac { 2n }{ 2n+1 } \\ { a }_{ 2n-1 }=-\frac { 2n-1 }{ 2n } $$

Comment: The limit of a2n is 1 yet the limit of a2n-1 is -1. So it is divergent, correct?

Comment: So does that mean only when the limit of both a2n and a2n-1 have the same value, the sequence is convergent?

Comment: yes, you got it, this limit is divergent.And again yes, if all subsequences is unique then it converges

Answer (score 0):

The first one is correct. For the second one, notice what the limit of $\dfrac n {n+1}$ is and look at the alternation of signs.

Answer (score 0):

You can rearrange the $n$-term:

$$a_n=\frac{(-1)^nn}{n+1}=\frac{(-1)^nn+(-1)^n-(-1)^n}{n+1}=(-1)^n-\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}.$$

As $n\rightarrow\infty, \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}\rightarrow 0$ and $a_n \sim (-1)^n.$